# How to add min-height and min-width to jQuery .width and .height

Tags: jquery, html, css, window-resize

I have a single page site and am trying to set the min-height and width using CSS. But the jQuery seems to ignore my min sizes.

I am resizing my window using this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    resizePanel();
});
function resizePanel() {
    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();
    mask_width = width * $('.item').length;
    $('#wrapper, .item').css({width: width, height: height});
    $('#mask').css({width: mask_width, height: height});
}
```

The Html looks like this.

```
</head>
<body>


<div id="wrapper">
<div id="mask">

    <div id="item1" class="item">
    </div>

    <div id="item2" class="item">
    </div>

    <div id="item3" class="item">
    </div>

    <div id="item4" class="item">
    </div>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

each of these divs is positioned off screen using this CSS.

```
body, html {
height:100%;
width:100%;
margin:0;padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
#wrapper {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;left:0;
background-color:#ccc;
overflow:hidden;
}

#mask {
    width:400%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#eee;
}

.item {
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ddd;
    min-height:700px;
    min-width: 700px;
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly recieved.

Answer (score 1):

> **Value that is greatest will be rendered (height > min-height or
>   vice-versa)**

So if you are designing your web-page then keep this think in mind.

***1.with greater `min-height` and `min-width`***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
    min-height:200px;
    min-width: 200px;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>This element has greater min-height and min-width.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

***2.with greater `height` and `width`***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
    min-height:50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>This element has greater height and width</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery actually overwrites your `min-width` and `min-height` by `width` and `height` so what you could do is this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    resizePanel();
});
function resizePanel() {
    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();
    mask_width = width * $('.item').length;
    $('#wrapper').css({width: width, height: height});
    $('.item').css({minWidth: width, minHeight: height});
    $('#mask').css({width: mask_width, height: height});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it seems that it causes some unpredictable things to happen with my site, it scrolls horizontaly to reveal each item on the page. But now it messes up once i resize the browser window...looks like im going to have to leave it to completely resize or just rethink my design...

Comment: @Aaron , it is not jquery problem, i have tested simple code in plain html, it is still not working..! `div {
    height:100vh;
    width:100%;border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
    min-height:100px;
    min-width: 100px;
}`